# Jenkins crashs on concurrent grunt task

Tags: concurrency, jenkins, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to build run a grunt based build task in Jenkins, that was created with a yeoman generator.

Jenkins is able to successfully run `npm install` and `bower install`.

**Problem:** As I run `grunt` Jenkins crashs: It can't be reached via the browser, it loses the entry of the build task and it has to be restartet.

If I watch the **console output, while the task runs**, the last messages i get before the server crashes is:

```
[4mRunning "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task[24m [32m>>
[39mWarning: There are more tasks than your concurrency limit. After
this limit[32m
>> [39mis reached no further tasks will be run until the current tasksare[32m
>> [39mcompleted. You can adjust the limit in the concurrent task options
```

**What I tried so far:**

1. I tried to setup Jenkins to allow 4 build processes.
2. I also tried to limit it to 1 build process. Both didn't change anything.
3. I can't really change the grunt task, as I would have to do it in more than 30 projects.

**Question:** Is there a way to make it possible to run concurrent grunt tasks, without crashing?

**Part of the Gruntfile.js:**

```
// Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
concurrent: {
  server: [
    'compass:server'
  ],
  test: [
    'compass'
  ],
  dist: [
    'compass:dist',
    'imagemin',
    'svgmin'
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Although adben's answer is right, he didn't explain where to set that `limit`. It is in your Gruntfile, this is how it should look for an example with 2 concurrent tasks:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    concurrent: {
        target: {
            tasks: [ 'watch', 'nodemon:run' ],
            options: {
                limit: 2,
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Here is the documentation of [grunt concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the Number of CPU cores to use i.e.:

```
options:
      limit: 2
      logConcurrentOutput: true
```

Comment: Where should i put this limit? in Grunt or in Jenkins?